# How to return string which will be equal to the called endpoint with all query parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We're using Spring rest api.
We have some endpoint which can be called with SOME query params.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<SomeObject>> someMethod(@RequestParam(required = false) MultiValueMap<String, String> params)
```

And we don't know in advance which params it will receive.
So we're using MultiValueMap and then just handle it.
But in the response we should return String which represents this endpoint with all the parameters.
For example, if a client calls it as

```
/someendpoint?param1=value1&params2=value2&params3=[value3a,value3b]
```

we just need to return this string.
Of cause we can construct this string iterating through the map.
But I think spring has a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<SomeObject>> someMethod(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(required = false) MultiValueMap<String, String> params) {

     String url = request.getRequestURL().toString() + (request.getQueryString() == null ? "" : "?" + request.getQueryString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Spring HATEOAS [ControllerLinkBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/ControllerLinkBuilder.html).

Maybe you could use it generate URLs from the given parameters. Havent tried it though.

```
List<Order> methodLinkBuilder = methodOn(YourController.class).someMethod(params);
Link selfLink = linkTo(methodLinkBuilder).withRel("self");
```